# How do I remove/hide the image after the loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to javascript, I'm creating a chrome packaged app, what I want to do is to hide the loading image after the loop. This is just part of my code since I'm just pointing out on how to hide the image after the loop.

```
 function AppMain()
    {
        jQuery("#loginID").hide();
        if(userLog == false)
        {
            jQuery.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'something.aspx',
                            data: {action: 'someSearch', word: 'Wednesday', count: '4', page: '1'},
                            success: function(data){
                                    var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                                    var htmlInfo='';

                                    for(i=0; i<json.length; i++)
                                    {
                                        var htmlCode = '<img class="full-image" src="/img/loading.png">' //this is the loading image
                                        htmlInfo = htmlInfo + htmlCode;
                                    }
//what do i need to add here so that the img will hide after the loop? 
                            }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: `htmlInfo` is not appended anywhere is it ? `$(htmlInfo).hide()` will hide it...

Comment: it's appended in the html, i just removed the part of the code

Answer (score 0):

Add `$('.full-image').remove();` or `$('.full-image').hide();`

Comment: That will also hide or remove any *other* images (or non-image elements) with that class anywhere on the page.

Comment: `$('.full-image')` will only work if elements are appended in `DOM`

Answer (score 0):

add an id to the image like:

```
var htmlCode = '<img class="full-image" id="loadingImg" src="/img/loading.png">' //this is the loading image
```

then use jquery you can remove it in a clear way:

```
$("#loadingImg").remove()
```

Comment: this is actually what I did, but it didn't do the trick I don't know why

Comment: do you append the text to the html page??

Comment: ah you add the image multiple times?
then you have to add a class instead of an id. e.g. `class="loadingImg"` and then you can do `$(".loadingImg").remove()`. but where do you add the htmlCode to the DOM?

Comment: @madalinivascu yes i'm appending the text to html page